# Multiple OHLC datasets in one image

Tags: java, jfreechart, stocks

How can I chart multiple datasets in one image using JFreeChart ?

Essentially I want to chart a stock's price and it's moving average line in one image.

I've tried getting the XYPlot and adding the second dataset, but it does not work.

```
DefaultOHLCDataset dataset = new DefaultOHLCDataset(symbol, items);
DefaultOHLCDataset dataset2 = new DefaultOHLCDataset(symbol, evs);
JFreeChart chart2 = ChartFactory.createHighLowChart(
    symbol, "minutes", "prices", dataset, true);        
chart2.getXYPlot().setDataset(1, dataset2);
```

Or is there any specialized java library for stock trading application that's easier to use?

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [`DefaultOHLCDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/DefaultOHLCDataset.html) is "A simple implementation of the `OHLCDataset` interface. This implementation supports only one series." You probably want [`OHLCSeriesCollection`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/ohlc/OHLCSeriesCollection.html), which also implements `OHLCDataset` and can hold more than one [`OHLCSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/ohlc/OHLCSeriesCollection.html).