# JFreeChart Line graph plot OHLCDataItem

Tags: java, graph, jfreechart, candlestick-chart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple OHLC datasets in one image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221844/multiple-ohlc-datasets-in-one-image)

Hi So I have plotted a candleStick graph using a `OHLCDataItem` array, and I am also plotting a line graph over the top using the same array, however at the moment the line graph plots the "open" variable of the `OHLCDataItem`. How do I get it to plot a different variable.
i.e. the constructor is:

```
OHLCDataItem(java.util.Date date, double open, double high, double low, double close, double volume)
```

So currently this is my code setting up the graph:

```
List<OHLCDataItem> data = getData(stockSymbol);
OHLCDataItem[] dataItems = data.toArray(new OHLCDataItem[data.size()]);
XYDataset generalDataSet = new DefaultOHLCDataset(stockSymbol, dataItems);
XYPlot mainPlot = new XYPlot(generalDataSet, domainAxis, rangeAxis, candleStickRenderer);

mainPlot.setDataset(1,  generalDataSet);
mainPlot.setRenderer(1, LineRenderer);
```

This line: `mainPlot.setDataset(1,  generalDataSet);`
is setting up the plot for the line graph, but I cant figure out how to graph a different variable than "open". I think it must be straight forward, but I cant grasp it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably want OHLCSeries and OHLCSeriesCollection (which implements XYDataset), instead of an OHLCDataItem array and DefaultOHLCDataset.

Comment: [code]
List<OHLCDataItem> data = getData(stockSymbol);
  
  OHLCDataItem[] dataItems = data.toArray(new OHLCDataItem[data.size()]);
  OHLCSeries dataserieslist = new OHLCSeries(data.addAll(data));
  
  
  XYDataset generalDataSet = new DefaultOHLCDataset(stockSymbol, dataItems);
  XYDataset testSet = new OHLCSeriesCollection();
  testSet.setGroup(dataserieslist)
  
  XYPlot mainPlot = new XYPlot(generalDataSet, domainAxis, rangeAxis, candleStickRenderer);
  
  mainPlot.setDataset(1,  testSet);
  mainPlot.setRenderer(1, LineRenderer);
[/code]
Sorry Im struggling a bit?

Comment: Please edit your question with new code, where it will be readable.